# multiple instances of hide/show div on page

Tags: toggle, hide, show

my div toggling script works if there is only one set of elements to toggle, but not when there are multiple instances per page. need multiple divs to toggle independently/separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/2zCe5/

```
$(function(){
$('.showFull').click(function() {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});   
});
```

because the final code will be output dynamically via the wordpress loop, a solution using data-id's (such as in this threads accepted answer [How to create multiple instances of show/hide div in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419937/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-show-hide-div-in-jquery)) appeals to me because i could populate that with the post id.

unfortunately i don't have enough JS knowledge to tweak that solution to fit my needs, hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery traversing to go up to the parent 'storeitem' level and then work your way back down. This way, all the toggling stays within the given storeitem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2zCe5/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('.showFull').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.storeitem').find('.targetDiv').hide();
        $(this).parents('.storeitem').find('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    });   
});
```

There's probably of more graceful way to write it but this is the idea.